# Productionizing Docker On AWS With Django & Postgres:

Tags: django, postgresql, amazon-web-services, docker, docker-compose

I have been stumped as of late trying to figure out a cloud environment setup that can support my 'dockerized' Python Django project. The architecture of my application is simple; I have a web service, a redis service and a database service (see my compose yml file below).

My confusion is finding the correct path of moving a local setup that is stood up via the docker compose yml file to a production like environment. I absolutely love the docker compose utility and hope to use a similar config file for my production environment; however, I am finding that most container based approaches on the cloud are far more complex than this... This [guide](https://www.ybrikman.com/writing/2015/11/11/running-docker-aws-ground-up/) has been my favorite so far, but it doesn't dive into databases and other depended on components (which leaves out the necessary nitty gritty stuff!).

Questions:

- Should I move away from trying to use docker-compose on a production environment?
- Should I use a database that is not containerized? If I shouldn't, how do I configure the containerized web service to an Amazon RDS instance?
- Should I break apart my docker-compose.yml into individual docker files? Should I write script to start these containers to stand up the environment?
- Is there a solid tutorial that I am not finding to do this sort of thing? I am baffled on how overly simple a lot of the guides are out there that dont help with even remotely more complex applications than "Hello World".

I have also found AWS and Heroku to lack common features that I would expect based on how popular docker is. Is this a commonly held opinion? Heroku does not help or advocate for setting up databases in containers and AWS is still behind for users trying to use docker-compose yml files that are written in v3.

Any recommendations are much appreciated... Ive been hacking away with no solid conclusions for the past 3 nights.

```
version: '3.3'

services:
  db:
    restart: always
    image: postgres
    networks:
      - webnet
  redis:
    restart: always
    image: redis:latest
    expose:
      - "6379"
    networks:
      - webnet
  web:
    restart: always
    build: .
    command: make start
    volumes:
      - .:/code
    deploy:
      replicas: 5
      resources:
        limits:
          cpus: "0.1"
          memory: 50M
      restart_policy:
        condition: on-failure
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    networks:
      - webnet
    depends_on:
      - db
      - redis

networks:
  webnet:
```

Comment: You can use Elastic Beanstalk for your server's docker and then use RDS and ElastiCache for Redis. It's not generally recommended to run a database in a container. You can also try the new AWS Fargate.